# KeyError 'image' when uploading image to flask backend from React frontend

Tags: reactjs, http, flask, server, fetch

i am trying to upload data from my react frontend to flask backend however after an upload i get a following error:  *"400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.KeyError: 'image'"* But when I make an Image upload using Postman form-data it works just fine. Is there something wrong with my fetch request?

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";


export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data:any) => fetch("http://127.0.0.1:4000/upload",
  {
       method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      body: data,
  }).then(() => console.log(data))
   
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input ref={register} type="file" name="image" required/>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here is the code of my backend:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='.')
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = file_mb_max * 1024 * 1024
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)

app.secret_key = app_key


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in extensions


def clear_folder(upload_dest):
    for f in os.listdir(upload_dest):
        os.remove(os.path.join(upload_dest, f))


@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("DEBUG ----",request.files['image'])
        file = request.files['image']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(upload_dest, filename))
            file_path = os.path.join(upload_dest, filename)
            type(file)
            shot_type = detect_shot(file_path)
            # clear_folder(upload_dest)
            return jsonify({'shotType': shot_type})

    return redirect('/upload')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('to upload files navigate to http://127.0.0.1:4000/upload')
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=4000, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the fetch request to include the formData which contains the image element,

```
const form = new FormData();
form.append('image', data);
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:4000/upload", {
   method: 'POST',
   body: form,
})
```

Not sure about "mode" but you can try with or without to see which solution works.